# access the info of the user that created the post

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am making a react-native mobile app and I am having trouble passing the users info that created the post to the home page in the post detail. I can pass the userID but for some reason when I add the rest of the info to the payload I can't create a post. Please help.

**BACKEND**
This is the requireAuth file that requires authentication before performing a tast. My code for the user is here as well at the bottom---

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = mongoose.model("User");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const { authorization } = req.headers;

  if (!authorization) {
    return res.status(401).send({ error: "You must be logged in." });
  }

  const token = authorization.replace("Bearer ", "");
  jwt.verify(token, "mySecretKey", async (err, payload) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).send({ error: "You must be logged in." });
    }

    const { userId, name, phone, email } = payload;

    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    req.user = user;
    console.log(req.user);
    next();
  });
};
```

This is the POST route for the Item---

```
router.post("/items", requireAuth, async (req, res) => {
  const { title, category, detail, condition, price } = req.body;

  if (!title || !category || !detail || !condition || !price) {
    return res.status(422).send({
      error: "You must provide a  title, category, detail, condition, and price"
    });
  }
  try {
    const item = new Item({
      title,
      category,
      detail,
      condition,
      price,
      userId: req.user._id
    });
    await item.save();
    res.send(item);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(422).send({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

**FRONT-END**
This is my createItem function in the itemContext file---

```
const createItem = dispatch => async ({
  title,
  category,
  detail,
  condition,
  price
}) => {
  try {
    const response = await sellerApi.post("/items", {
      title,
      category,
      detail,
      condition,
      price
    });
    //this is the other place the error might be happening i need this to save in the phone local storage
    dispatch({ type: "create_item", payload: response.data });
    navigate("Home");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

All I am trying to do it is when the post is being displayed so is the info of the post creator

Comment: How your user's and post's model looks like?

Comment: also you are not requiring jsonwebtoken in the auth file

Answer (score 1):

**For existing post in the database**: If you are referencing your user in post model like this

```
const Post = mongoose.model('Post', {
    // other fields
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    }
})
```

then you can use populate to fetch user of that post.

```
const post= await Post.findById('5c2e505a3253e18a43e612e6')
await post.populate('userId').execPopulate()
console.log(post.userId)
```